# Minimalistic Framebuffer showing text and progress only

Tags: linux, embedded, console, framebuffer

I have an embedded linux system with framebuffer only. Normally a Qt Application is running. During update situation the application is stoped and I would like to use the framebuffer device to show simple text and a progress bar.

The whole thing should run out of a C/C++ application (not a shell/script) and should be as lightweight and with as less dependencies to the OS as possible. I will not need any keyboard, mouse, touchscreen or other input, just output to framebuffer.

Does anyone have a tool recommondation for me? Thanks :)

Comment: Is the text fixed (so it can be copied as a bitmap) or does it need to be flexible (so you will need a library to render the text)?

Comment: @Philippos flexible would be better, otherwise I would have to create bitmaps for every possible error message that could go wrong during the update.